# How to find 2 numbers and combine them with delimiters in python?

Tags: python

Ok i have an xml file that will have Id numbers matched up with their qty numbers.
they are nested pretty far down in the xml, im assuming that is making it more problematic. So i need to parse the xml for these numbers and ultimately print them out in this format:126144/1+0000126151/1+0000167031/1+0000227496/3+, the 6 digit number being the id and the number before the + being the qty.
here is a sample of the xml:

```
<NAXML-BusDoc version="1.0"> 
<TransmissionHeader> 
    <TransmissionId/> 
    <TransmissionDate>20081031</TransmissionDate> 
    <TransmissionTime>173256</TransmissionTime> 
    <TransmissionStatus actionType="original"/> 
</TransmissionHeader> 
<Parties> 
    <Supplier> 
        <Name identType="CustVendID" ident="999999">Co</Name> 
    </Supplier> 
    <Buyer> 
        <Name identType="FEIN" ident="">PDIU M Mart Test</Name> 
    </Buyer> 
</Parties> 
<PurchaseOrder> 
    <PurchaseOrderNumber>12345</PurchaseOrderNumber> 
    <ShipTo identType="CustStoreID" ident="20        ">
        <Name>M Mart #20</Name>
        <Address/> 
        <City/> 
        <State/> 
        <PostalCode/> 
    </ShipTo> 
    <Dates> 
        <OrderDate>20160106</OrderDate>
    </Dates> 
    <PurchaseOrderDetail> 
        <Terms/> 
        <LineItem count="1"> 
            <PurchaseOrderUnit> 
                <PurchaseOrderUnitId identType="VIN" ident="**021360**"/> 
                <PurchaseOrderUnitQty UOMBasis="pack">**10**</PurchaseOrderUnitQty>
                <BuyersCost UOMBasis="pack">12.1200</BuyersCost> 
                <Taxes taxable="No"/> 
            </PurchaseOrderUnit> 
            <RetailUnitPricing>
```

and here is my code that i have so far:

```
from xml.dom import minidom
from itertools import imap
xmldoc = minidom.parse("newsample.xml")
itemlist = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("PurchaseOrderUnitId")
quantity = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("PurchaseOrderUnitQty")
for i in itemlist:
for s in quantity:
print "0000"+(i.attributes["ident"].value),"/"+s.firstChild.nodeValue+"+",
```

which outputs each id number 6 times and i dont know why.

0000021360 /10+ 0000021360 /2+ 0000021360 /10+ 0000021360 /5+ 0000021360 /10+ 0000021360 /15+ 0000021360 /6+ 0000023408 /10+ 0000023408 /2+ 0000023408 /10+

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: Def not asking anybody to write code for me, i was still editing my post to include my sample file and the code that i have tried so far

Comment: Write the whole question BEFORE you post it.

Comment: Thanks i should have thought of that.

Answer (score 0):

Python is a very picky language when it comes to indentation. I recommend you read this [post on indentation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation). I think your specific issue is coming from here:

```
final = ["0000",(i.attributes["ident"].value),"/","+",s.firstChild.nodeValue]
    ",".join(str(bit) for bit in final) # this line is tabbed, but that's not allowed!
        print final # this line is tabbed twice, but it shouldn't be tabbed at all!
```

As for the rest of your code, I'm not very familiar with xml, but it seems you would be best served by reading the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/) or the [Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/index.html).

Comment: Thank you for reponse i really appreciate it. i will be checking out all of those links. I have taken the tabs out of both of those lines liked you suggested and it doesnt throw an error but it doesnt print the formatting i'm looking for. I guess what im looking for more then anything is, am i on the right track?

Comment: Like I said, I haven't worked a lot with xml, but my initial impression on reading your code is that there seem to be some logical errors. I know you want to start programming useful things as soon as you start, but you may be better off just learning the basics and working your way up. A website I found very helpful for learning python was [hackerrank.com](https://www.hackerrank.com/domains/python/py-introduction)